# Adding multiple Models in a Single view

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, model, webforms

In my ASP.NET Web forms app, I have a Model that contains a property of Collection of other Model :

```
public class FloorPattern
{
    public FloorPattern()
    {        }

    public FloorPattern(string projId, int flrNum)
    {
        ProjectId = projId;
        FloorNumber = flrNum;
    }

    public int FloorNumber { get; set; }

    public int Units { get; set; }


    public ICollection<UnitPattern> UnitPattern { get; set; }
```

I scafolded `FloorPattern` model, but it doesn't contain any thing for `UnitPatern` input/dispaly . I am looking at when user enters value in "Units" property, the `UnitPattern` creates a list of that many items & lets user enter details.

How can I get this am not able to get it ? Can you please help me in the same ???

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not used to webforms, apologies if this does not help.

What about making it virtual? Does lazy loading

```
 public virtual ICollection<UnitPattern> UnitPattern { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Hasta, but that doesn't make any difference for what I am looking.